# How to Create project jar file through Eclipse for Spring Boot Gradle Project?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, spring-boot

How to Create project jar file through Eclipse for Spring Boot Gradle Project.
I do not want to create it through command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gradle task view in eclipse to do this.

Make sure you've add the plugin *buildship* through the eclipse marketplace, 
Once you've added the plugin (and completed some basic setup, see link below) you will have a `Gradle Tasks` tab that you can use to execute any of the build tasks you'd like.

See [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) for more information (including screenshots)

Comment: Thanks@Robert...Very much useful for me.

Comment: No probem Satish, if you feel this question has resolved your answer please use the checkmark to the left to mark it as answered, if the question is helpful but does not resolve your issue feel free to upvote as well.